# How to get parentID from file resource in Google drive API python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

in file resource here : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

how to get the only parentID from parents in the file's resource I got?

Answer (score 0):

In python, if the file resource is `f` and there is only 1 parent:

```
parentId = f['parents'][0]['id']
```